# I couldn't get the point that " i "represents index inside the for loop

Tags: c++14

When we code somthing in the  for Loop like

```
#include <iostream>
int main (){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int arr[n];
    For (int i =0 ; i<n ; i+2 ) {
        cin >> arr[i];
        if (arr[i] % 2 ==0) cout << "even";
        else cout << " odd" ; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In this code will the index of `i` will be updated by adding 3 or the value of index i ?

Comment: Your code contains compilation error.

Comment: All the written above must be included in that grey box

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: please format your code with code fences to make the code readable.

Comment: please explain more about your problem/expectation from the above code snippet to help your question be understandable.

Answer (score 0):

It's a  very common problem  for beginners.
According to your "`for loop`" `(int i =0 ; i<n ; i+2 )` you're starting index is 0 and when you do `i+2` it means increasing the value of the array index (`i`) by 2 and after updating the `i` value  you reach array index 2 and then 4,6,8...

See some example

- `i++` or `i=i+1` -> both means increasing the value of `i` by 1;
- `i+2` -> means increasing  the value of `i` by 2;
- `i+3` -> means increasing  the value of `i` by 3;

I think after reading this your doubt will be clear

Comment: I think both the OP and you have confused the third part of the `for` loop: instead of `i+2` it should be `i+=2` (similar in the examples you've made).

Comment: bro are you all right .According to me when we write `for loop` then `1+2` or `i+=2` both are equal

Comment: No, `i+2` is an expression which result is never used (it's not assigned to anything), while `i+=2` (equivalente to `i=i+2`) _does_ the assignment. The first one (`i+2`) will result in a warning about the result never being used and in a never-ending loop when executed.

Comment: sorry i did n't get you're point .Please elaborate you're point with some example

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<10; i+2) { std::cout << i; }` will print `0` forever and never end, while `for (int i=0; i<10; i+=2) { std::cout << i; }` will print `02468` as expected.

Comment: thank you so much .I never pointed out that point.